# check date exist or not in database asp mvc and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

hello i want  to check if date existe in database or not and if existe  the user receive a message error so i work with asp mvc and try to find soltion but no success can you help me please

this is my controller to get the date event :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Checkdate(DateTime StartDate)
    {
        return Json(!db.Events.Any(u => u.StartDate== StartDate), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

this is my script :

```
     function CheckAvailability() {
            var StartDate = $('#txtStart').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Checkdate",
                data: '{StartDate: "' + StartDate + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var message = $("#message");
                    if (response) {
                        //Email available.
                        message.css("color", "green");
                        message.html("date is available");
                    }
                    else {
                        //Email not available.
                        message.css("color", "red");
                        message.html("date is NOT available");
                    }
                }
            });
        };
        function ClearMessage() {
            $("#message").html("");
        };
```

this is my html :

```
           <input type="text" id="txtStart" class="form-control" onkeyup="ClearMessage()"/>
          <input id="btnCheck" type="button" value="Show Availability" onclick="CheckAvailability()" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by `no success`. What error do you get? Have you tried `debug` your  `Checkdate`?

Comment: the message error  not display in form i don't know why

Comment: Check your `Network` tab on browser and see what response you get. Put `debugger` in your ajax `success` and check what do you get in `response`. With the information you have provided it is very difficult to help.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: CheckAvailability is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Calendar:146)

Comment: Try moving your scripts in @render scripts section. Don't put it on the top of the view.

Comment: the condition in my controller it"s true ??

Comment: Is your onclick event triggering already?